# Installation of Solaris 11 on Sun Fire T1000

Tags: solaris

I just want to install Solaris 11.4 on my Sun Fire T1000. I have successfully configured install server on VirtualBox, how it described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/installsvr-1.html#scrolltoc)

After that, I connected to ALOM of T1000, and tried to boot using network.
After that I saw such messages:

```
Boot device: /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/network@1,1  File and args: -v - install
1000 Mbps full duplex  Link up
<time unavailable> wanboot info: WAN boot messages->console
<time unavailable> wanboot info: configuring /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/network@1,1

1000 Mbps full duplex  Link up
<time unavailable> wanboot info: http://10.100.8.28:5555/cgi-bin/wanboot-cgi
Found 10.100.8.28 @ 8:0:27:ca:20:7a
<time unavailable> wanboot progress: wanbootfs: Read 368 of 368 kB (100%)
<time unavailable> wanboot info: wanbootfs: Download complete
Tue Sep 24 10:27:26 wanboot progress: miniroot: Read 408100 of 408100 kB (100%)
Tue Sep 24 10:27:26 wanboot info: miniroot: Download complete
|
SC Alert: Host System has Reset
'cp
SC Alert: Host system has shut down.
```

And then my Sun Fire T1000 just reboot.

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solaris 11.4 is not supported on the T1000](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60973/glmru.html) (bolding mine):

> **Platform Support**
>
> Oracle Solaris 11.4 supports systems based on the Oracle SPARC T4 or
>   later processors; the Fujitsu SPARC64 X, X+, or XII processors; or x64
>   CPUs supporting either the Intel EM64T or AMD AMD64 instruction sets.
>
> You will not be able to upgrade to Oracle Solaris 11.4 on any of the
>   following platforms. See Oracle Solaris 11.3 Support (Doc ID
>   2382427.1) for information about keeping these systems up to date with critical fixes for Oracle Solaris 11.3 until you can upgrade the
>   hardware:
>
> - SPARC Enterprise M3000, M4000, M5000, M8000, and M9000 systems that use SPARC64 VI, VII, or VII+ CPUs.
> - **Platforms based on UltraSPARC T1 CPUs - Sun Fire T1000 and T2000, Sun SPARC Enterprise T1000 and T2000, Netra CP3060, Netra T2000, and
>     Sun Blade T6300**
> - Platforms based on UltraSPARC T2 CPUs - Sun SPARC Enterprise T5120 and T5220, Sun Blade T6230, Netra CP3260, and Netra T5220
> - Platforms based on UltraSPARC T2+ CPUs: Sun SPARC Enterprise T5140, T5240 and T5440, Sun Blade T6340, Sun Netra T6340, and Netra T5440
> - Platforms based on SPARC T3 CPUs: SPARC T3-1, T3-1B, T3-2 and T3-4, Netra SPARC T3-1, and Netra SPARC T3-1BA
> - Sun Java Workstation models: W1100z, W2100z
> - Sun Ultra Workstation models: 20, 20 M2, 40, 40 M2
> - Sun Fire server models: V20z, V40z, X2100, X2100 M2, X2200 M2, X4100, X4100 M2, X4140, X4200, X4200 M2, X4240, X4440, X4540, X4600,
>     X4600 M2, X4640
> - Sun Blade server modules: X6220, X6240, X6440, X8400, X8420, X8440
> - Netra X4200 M2